# Test if bits repeat in a number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm looping over all length i bitstrings and was wondering how to tell if it is a 
repetition of a previous bitstring? Basically I want to skip `11`, `1010`, `1111`, `0101`, `101101` etc but not `1011`, `1100`, `1000`, `101001` etc

These bit-strings are the periods of binary numbers so if they repeat it generates the same number which will throw off my data processing program.

The repeating sequences need to be adjacent and cover all of `j` without overflow

```
    skip = false;
    for(int i = 1; i<=n/2 && !skip; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
            skip = true;
            for(int k=1; k<=n/i; k++) {
                if(((j&(j >> (i*k)))&((1<<i) - 1)) != (j&((1<<i) - 1))){
                    skip = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(skip) continue;
```

This is my current attempt but it seems to fail to detect any.

`n` is the length of the bit-string in bits

`j` is the bit-string

EDIT: Fixed a few typing errors, but now it detects `10` but not `11`

Comment: still don't know what this means: "repetition of a previous bitstring"

Comment: `skip == true;` does nothing. The `if(skip) continue;` outside of the loop does nothing and you pulled the variable `j` out of seemingly nowhere. We need a bit more information here about what you're trying to do and what `j` and `i` are.

Comment: If it repeats inside of it, so if it is equal to some other bit-string repeated multiple-times inside of it.(ex 1010 is 10 repeated twice)

Comment: Please make your k an i and your i to length or n

Comment: @Josh this is inside of a larger loop so the `if(skip) continue` should just skip over this `j` value.

Comment: Is there any chance you could get away with not skipping it? As far as I can tell, the test isn't going to be pretty

Comment: please specify your problem in a complete manner. State what "repetition of a bitstring" means. Can any length sequence repeat? do the repeating sequences have to be adjacent, etc?

Comment: Possibly, but this is generating data and if I repeat values then the data processing gets a lot uglier.

Comment: sry dude, still unclear what you want

Comment: Seems clear to me, so don't go voting "unclear". Just read better.

Comment: @bolov is it clearer now?

Comment: since you need to cover all j, wouldn’t that mean that the first half has to be equal to the second half?

Comment: You want to skip "11" but not "1100" but "1100" has "11" in it so you skipped that.  Then it has "00" which you should skip too, since it is a repeat.  It doesn't sound like the problem is defined well enough to solve it.

Comment: If (i % k == 0) is first time true when k == 1 × i, but the loop conditions says k <= i / 2, are you sure the loop body is even entered? Have you debugged it?

Comment: @MartinMeeser yes it is entered and repeated the expected number of times. If k > n/2 then for all m>1 k*m>n

Comment: Does `0011`, `0111`, `111`, `101` repeat ?

Comment: Let's say n is 10. The body is entered with i=1, i=2, i=5. Can you please help us with a comment in your code why you are doing this?

Comment: `111` repeats but the others do not. One of the answers(that seems to have been deleted now) actually had a solution. The divisible by temp when temp starts at 1 and then is for(int m = i; m<n; m+=i) temp |= 1 << m;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want in a completely different way.

Look at decimal numbers to reduce confusion. For example, the number 4545 is a repetition of the number 45. To detect this, you can divide by 101, and see that the result is less than 100.

In c++:

```
if (j % 101 == 0 && j / 101 < 100)
```

Now replace base 10 by base 2:

```
if (j % 5 == 0 && j / 5 < 4)
```

What if number of digits is not 2 but `n`?

- Replace 4 by `1 << n`
- Replace 5 by `(1 << n) + 1`

What if you want to check repetition of 3 bit-strings? I am not sure you want it, but it seems possible.

Edit: I am too lazy to develop all the details, but consider the following hints:

- Detect repetition of 3 patterns, 4 digits in each: divide by 100010001
- 100010001 = 999999999999 / 9999 (in decimal notation)
- It's easy to figure out the general formula for what to divide by
- To calculate a power of 10, you could use `pow`; fortunately, you actually need powers of 2 instead, so use `1 << whatever` to raise 2 to whatever power

Comment: I need to check the repetition of `i` bit-strings for all `i<n`

Comment: So if I understand it right then the code for it would be `if(j*((1<<i)-1) % ((1<<n)-1) == 0) skip = true;`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern of the repetition may appears only a size which is a divisor of `n`.

So for `n` even, it is simple, just check both half bit to see if they are identical

```
bool does_bits_repeat(int n, unsigned b)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        const unsigned high = b >> (n / 2);
        // (high & b) is equivalent to (high & low)
        return (high & b) == high;
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The odd part is more tricky. you have to found the divisors `d` of `n`
and with `k` from

```
unsigned k = 1;
for (int i = 0; i != n; i += d) {
    k = k << d | 1;
}
// for n == 15, we have
//    d == 1, k = binary 111111111111111 (1 repeated 15 times)
//    d == 3, k = binary 001001001001001 (001 repeated 5 times)
//    d == 5, k = binary 000010000100001 (00001 repeated 3 times)
```

test if `j` is divisible by `k`.